# Generate Java Client from Big WSDL File

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have a wsdl file, and I want to create a client that will call a service from that wsdl file.

The main issue that the wsdl file has more than 300 method , so using tools to generate client code is not an option , i already tried to use eclipse tools , but the stub class was very big (more than allowed 65536 ).

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can inline some methods? what are you using to generate the client? Maybe you can try another generator who doesn't produce so much methods. The last resort is to use something lower level, like [apache xml-rpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/xmlrpc2/client.html)

Comment: is this problem solved? if so how did you handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Having a service exposing 300 methods is the problem.
Split your methods across services and you'll be able to use standard tools to generate the client stubs.

Comment: This is the issue , i cannot split the service ! , any other solution ?